# Usar los props Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo la duda de como usar los props en un componente, ahora mismo lo tengo montado así pero me da error la function retDataProps que está dentro del created()

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="sendToView">{{ msg }}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "button-lvl",
  props: ['msg', 'view'],
  data(){
    return { dView: this.$props.view }
  },
  created(){
    retDataProps: () => {
      return [this.msg, this.view]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendToView: () => {
      const dataProp = this.retDataProps()
      console.log(dataProp)
    }
  }
};
```

simplemente es un boton al que le llegan tanto el texto a mostrar como de la vista donde se encuentra, para posteriormente saber a que vista mandar al usuario una vez clickado.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos el mensaje de tu error?

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza simplemente no funciona

Comment: Ok. Lo que noto de la función `retDataProps` son 3 puntos importantes. **1.** El primero es que no veo que esté inicializado en ninguna parte, es decir, no hiciste por ejemplo un `let retDataProps` o un `const retDataProps`.  **2.** En segundo lugar está mal definida, porque no debería definirse con los dos puntos ":" si no con un igual "=", o sea  `retDataProps = () =>...`. **3.** Y el tercer punto es que veo que luego en la función `sendToView` estás llamándola con la palabra reservada `this`. Eso no va funcionar porque `retDataProps` no está definido dentro de `data` o en `computed`.

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza me funciono! mil gracias, otra pregunta, hay algún método para cambiar de componente haciendo click al botón? o hay que usar vue-router?

Comment: Excelente, como veo que te sirvieron los puntos que te mencioné, los pesaré en limpio como una respuesta a tu pregunta para que así quede bien documentada. Por el otro lado, con respecto a tu otra pregunta te recomiendo que justamente abras una pregunta nueva para hacerla y pueda ser respondida correctamente, ya que esa nueva pregunta no se relaciona directamente con la que planteaste en este post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema principal que origina tu error tiene que ver directamente con la función `retDataProps`.

Veo al menos 3 puntos importantes que deberías corregir:

**1.** No veo que `retDataProps` esté inicializado en ninguna parte.

Cuando se crea una nueva variable siempre hay que hacerlo con `var`, `let` o `const`.

En tu caso por ejemplo podrías hacer un `let retDataProps` o un `const retDataProps`.

Aunque más adelante te explicaré que en realidad te conviene más hacer otra cosa con tu función.

**2.** Tu función `retDataProps` está mal definida.

Porque no debería definirse con los dos puntos "**:**", eso suele hacerse cuando se define un objeto JSON, como por ejemplo:

```
let helloWorld = {
  propOne: 1,
  propTwo: 2,
}
```

Fijate que el `helloWorld` se define con "**=**" mientras que sus props `propOne` y `propTwo` se definen con los "**:**".

No te olvides que Vue es un framework y que lo que estás usando en realidad es **JavaScript**, por lo que tienes que seguir sus mismas reglas de sintaxis.

Así que, volviendo a tu código y siguiendo el modelo del ejemplo anterior, podrías definir tu función de una forma parecida a esta:

```
const retDataProps = () => {
      return [this.msg, this.view]
}
```

**3.** Por ultimo noté que en la función `sendToView` estás llamando a la función `retDataProps` con la palabra reservada `this`.

Eso no va funcionar porque `retDataProps` estaría definida solo en el ciclo de vida de Vue `created()`. Entonces solo se puede acceder desde ahí.

Para poder acceder a una variable desde cualquier parte del componente con el `this`, Vue nos provee del [data](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Datos-y-Metodos) y el [computed](https://es.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Propiedades-Computadas).

En tu código, quizás podría serte útil colocar tu función dentro del `data` de la siguiente manera:

```
<script>

...

 data () {
   return {
     retDataProps: () => {
       return [this.msg, this.view]
     }
   }

 }

...

</script>
```

Fijate que en este caso sí puedes definir la función con los dos puntos porque el `data` retorna un objeto.

Si bien esta no sería una mala forma de usar el `data`, pienso que  cuando particularmente la variable se trata de una función, puede que sea más útil definirla en los `methods`.